# How to make keypress event of asp textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, keypress

Hi all i am writing calculation of varius asp textbox controls. I want my calculation being done with keypress event. Below code i am using but not working

.aspx page

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMaintCost onkeypress="calculateFinanceDetail(); return false;" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

.js file

```
function calculateFinanceDetail() {
            var txtMaintCost = $('input[id$=txtMaintCost]').val();
            var txtInstallCost = $('input[id$=txtInstallCost]').val();
            var txtFreightCost = $('input[id$=txtFreightCost]').val();
}
```

its not calling javascript function on keypress event...
If anyone have any idea than please help me in this..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Missing `"` at the end of id of textbox.

Change

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMaintCost onkeypress="calculateFinanceDetail(); return false;" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

To

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMaintCost" onkeypress="calculateFinanceDetail(); return false;" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Try using the ClientID of server controls. You might not having [static ids](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss.aspx) for server side controls. You do not have to use wild cards if you have fixed ids.

```
function calculateFinanceDetail() {
      var txtMaintCost = $('input[id=<%=txtMaintCost.ClientID%>]').val();
      var txtInstallCost = $('input[id=<%=txtInstallCost.ClientID%>]').val();
      var txtFreightCost = $('input[id=<%=txtFreightCost.ClientID%>]').val();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're missing quotes here `ID="txtMaintCost onkeypress="`, it should be `ID="txtMaintCost" "onkeypress="`