# Keypress of asp textbox returning only previous data

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using a asp textbox.I want to process the data on key press.my problem is when i am entering data i am only getting the previous data.

eg: entered 'hai',but getting only 'ha'on keypress

```
function CheckStreet(e) 
               {
                    var myStreet = new Array("ALEXANDER ST", "ALLEN AVE");
                    for (var i = 0; i < myStreet.length; i++)
                     {                        
                        if (e.value.toUpperCase() == myStreet[i])
                            alert("Please enter another");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Use `keyup` instead. `keypress` is fired when you press down on the button meaning that the textbox didn't update yet.

Comment: whats the problem in going with good old onclick??

Comment: your functionality is correct,you are facing problems with triggering events?

Comment: I am using some other process in keyup event.Can you suggest any other

Comment: any particular key that you want to press?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try keydown if you dont want to use keyup

```
$('id').on('keydown', function(e) { 
       //your action goes here!!!
    });
```

**javascript!!**

```
document.getElementById('id').onkeydown = function(event){
    event = event || window.event;
    var keycode = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
    if(keycode === 32){//any key has a unique code,try this.
        //your function
    }
}
```

If it is still not workin-->

Refer this-->[No keypress event for asp textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865287/no-keypress-event-for-asp-textbox?rq=1)

**UPDATE-->**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="myid" onkeypress="myFunction; return false;"></asp:TextBox>

function myFunction() {
     //your code!!!
}
```

Refer-->[How to make keypress event of asp textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094336/how-to-make-keypress-event-of-asp-textbox?rq=1)

Comment: By the way,which method helped??

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyup event instead. It will give you the updated text.
Besides not giving you the updated value - keypress only fires for printable characters, so it won't fire for backspace etc (at least not in IE)

Comment: I am using some other process in keyup event.Can you suggest any other

Comment: You can have more than one keyup event handler