# KeyPress Event of TextBox in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to get KeyPress Event for TextBox in ASP.NET, so I found this script, but it does not works for me

```
<title></title>

    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  lang="js">
        $(function () {
            $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").keypress(function () {
                alert("Wow; Its Work!.")
            });
        });
    </script> 

</head>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make keypress event of asp textbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094336/how-to-make-keypress-event-of-asp-textbox)

Comment: please add aspx code too

Comment: what error are you getting in console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your script is working very well the problem might be in jquery file its not found in the given location you can change the src for check

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeypress="myFunction()"></asp:TextBox>

 <script language="javascript">
    function myFunction()
    {
        alert('Key Press')
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Mostafa wrote, it is important to insert the script at the END of the page. So that the page can register the controls first.